# I got error defining Tailwind's active/hover classes in Laravel's app.css

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css

I want to apply tailwind-starter-kit in my Laravel 8 app
and I got the editor form from the html-login-page/login.html file, and the "Sign In" page of this form has classes :

```
<button class="bg-gray-900 text-white active:bg-gray-700 text-sm 
    font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg 
    outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full"
        type="button" style="transition: all 0.15s ease 0s;">
    Sign In
</button>
```

I want to set the class definitions in resources/css/app.css like the following.

```
.btn_full {
    @apply bg-gray-900 text-white active:bg-gray-700 text-sm 
    font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg 
    outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full;
}
```

But I get the following error.

> (623:39) /project_path/resources/css/app.css The `active:bg-gray-700`
> class does not exist, but `hover:bg-gray-700` does. If you're sure
> that `active:bg-gray-700` exists, make sure that any `@import`
> statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your
> CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.
>
> 621 |
> 622 |     .btn_frontend_submit_w_full {
> 623 |         @apply bg-gray-900 text-white active:bg-gray-700 text-sm font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg
> outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full;
> |                                       ^
> 624 |     }
> 625 |
>
> at processResult (/project_path/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:743:19)
> ...
>
> 1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the active or hover variants for the background property in tailwind.config.js

Comment: Looks,like not. Please, url how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control whether hover variants are enabled for a plugin in the variants section of your tailwind.config.js file. The active: prefix only applies to a utility when an element is active.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
        backgroundColor: ['hover','active'],
    }
  },
}
```